# MVC ASP.NET in Apache tomcat

Tags: asp.net-mvc, tomcat

I have made ​​an application in ASP.NET MVC and I would like to know if you run the application in Apache Tomcat? if possible how can I configure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mono is an option for you .

This May Helpfull :

http://buddylindsey.com/how-to-get-asp-net-mvc-2-working-with-mono-in-10-steps/ http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/90876/Running-ASP-NET-websites-on-Apache